# Inner join with Multiple condition on left join using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

following query is throwing error "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin"

```
from ph in context.PrPayfileHeaders
                     join pp in context.PrPayfileParticipants on ph.PayfileHeaderId equals pp.PayfileHeaderId
                     join sec in context.SecUsers on pp.AnalystUserId equals sec.UserId
                     join hp in context.HcmPerson on  // Error statement
                     new
                     {
                         key1 = pp.ParticipantEmpNumber,
                         key2 = ph.PayPeriod
                     }
                     equals
                     new
                     {
                         key1 = hp.EmployeeNumber,
                         key2 = hp.PeriodId
                     }
                     into fg
                     from fgi in fg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where ph.PayfileType == payFileType && ph.IntfControlId == intf_Control_Id && (region == null || ph.RegionName == region)
                     select new FinalPayFileInfo
                     {
                         Participant_id = pp.PayfileParticipantId,
                         Home_country = fgi.HomeCountry,
                         Region_name = ph.RegionName,
                         Analyst_name = sec.FirstName + " " + sec.LastName,
                         Full_name = fgi.FullName,
                         Department = pp.DeptNumber,
                         Cost_center = pp.CostCenter,
                         Local_currency = pp.LocalCurrency,
                         Comm_attribute1 = pp.CommAttribute1,
                         Comm_attribute2 = pp.CommAttribute2,
                         Comm_attribute3 = pp.CommAttribute3,
                         Comm_attribute4 = pp.CommAttribute4,
                         Comm_attribute5 = pp.CommAttribute5,
                         Comm_attribute6 = pp.CommAttribute6,
                         Comm_attribute7 = pp.CommAttribute7
                     };
```

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL. Joins are generated by EF itself, based on the relations between entities. If you have to use joins in LINQ, something is wrong with the model

Comment: If the `PayfileHeader` *class* (not table) had a `Participants` collection property, EF would load the related classes as needed